# Issue charging a 12V battery using solar charger

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, charger

I bought a 12V solar charger for vehicle batteries, because I am usually using wall chargers and I wanted to give green technology a try.

When I connect the solar charger to my battery, it shows 10V, and it was the same after two sunny days of charging. If I connect wall charger to that battery, it does show 13V and the battery does get charged after few hours.

When I measure solar charger outputs, it shows 18V, but if I connect it to battery, it falls to 10V.

When I measure wall charger output without the battery it shows 13V, if I connect it to battery, it still shows 13V.

Is there anything wrong with the solar charger? Or is the battery bad, because it will not allow to be charged from solar charger? What can I check? And how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: You might help us by adding a link to the solar charger into your question.

Comment: Sounds like the solar charger has not the proper current capability... wich is the Ah rating of the battery? and the maximum output current of the charger?

Comment: dude, it's normal for solar cells to drop under load - that's just what happens. what happens is as the battery charges and needs less current, the voltage rises - think of it as a laboratory power supply with "current control" mode on, but a voltage maximum still set to ~14V. Leave it connected for a long time and measure every hour, see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

and thanks for your replies.
I connected the solar charger to my car battery and after a few hours my car would not start. So, i decided that this solar charger has a n issue. I measured the charge and it was about 18V. The problem was that it was -18V and not +18V. The manufacturer installed the output cable so that it has an inverse polarity. 
It took me 2 batteries to destroy before realizing the above. I will contact the manufacturer to see what they suggest, an in the meantime, i just connect it deliberately wrong (minus of the solar charger to a plus of the battery) and it chargers fine.

Answer (score 0):

In order for **any** charger to work, its output voltage **MUST** be greater than the battery voltage when they're connected together.

Because the output resistance of a solar charger is often - if not always - higher than the internal resistance of the battery, when they're connected together it may seem that they're both at the same voltage but, if they're connected properly and the charger is insolated adequately, its voltage will rise to the point where it's enough higher than the battery voltage that it'll pump electrons into the battery. Perhaps only a few zillion per second, but still...

In order to troubleshoot your system, place an ammeter in series between the charger and the battery, making sure the solar charger is connected to the battery properly, (charger positive to battery positive) then insolate the charger's photovoltaic array and measure the direction and magnitude of the current through the meter.

If current is flowing **from** the charger **to** the battery, then most likely there isn't a really gross problem, but if it's only a little bit of current then most likely the charger's capacity is less than expected.

Just for grins, before you do anything else, check to make sure you've got the charger connected the right way round.